# CD Drive not showing up in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, compact-disc

I have Windows Vista SP 2 on a Acer TravelMate 5520. The CD/DVD drive is not showing up in Windows however it does show up in the BIOS and I was able to boot using a Linux Live CD.

The drive does not show up in the device manager (not even with a yellow question mark). How can I get the drive working again.

Comment: What is the model and brand of your CD/DVD Drive?

Comment: Did the drive come with any drivers?  Download those first and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Microsoft Fix-It tools [linked here](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cd_dvd_drive_problems).  These fix this more often than not (as hard as it is to believe) and should take you only a few moments as they're completely automated.